# Proper way to use PagingAndSortingRepository in my project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

The question is: **Where should I declare new sort or new pagination in proper way with Spring MVC?**

I was reading a lot of example usages and most of them are just inside "runable" (@SpringBootApplication) class, but I think it's not a good practice. (I decided to put it **inside my Controller**, but I'm not 100% sure about it. Maybe whole logic should be inside Service and just clear @RequestMapping should be in Controller?

Right now project structure looks like this:

[image: ProjectStructure]

I'm not sure if my code is important, but you can check it below.

```
@RestController
public class PhoneController {

@Autowired
private PhoneService phoneService;

@Autowired
private PhoneRepository phoneRepository;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/phones")
public List<Phone> getAllPhones() {return phoneService.getAllPhones();}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/phones/{id}")
public Phone getPhone(@PathVariable Long id){return phoneService.getPhone(id);}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/phones/{id}")
public void addPhone(@RequestBody Phone phone){
    phoneService.addPhone(phone);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/phones/{id}")
public void updatePhone(@RequestBody Phone phone, @PathVariable Long id){phoneService.updatePhone(id, phone);}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/phones/{id}")
public void deletePhone(@PathVariable Long id){ phoneService.deletePhone(id);}


//sorting...
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "phones/year/{temp}")
public List<Phone> getPhoneByYearOfReleaseGreaterThan(@PathVariable Integer temp){
    Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "brand"));
    List<Phone> phones = phoneRepository.findByYearOfReleaseGreaterThan(temp, sort);
    for(Phone p: phones){
        System.out.println(p);
    }
    return phones;
}


//pagination...
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "phones/quarter/{temp}")
public List<Phone> getPhoneByQuarterOfRelease(@PathVariable String temp){
Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "brand"));
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 5, sort);
List<Phone> phones = phoneRepository.findByQuarterOfRelease(temp, pageable);
    for (Phone p : phones) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
    return phones;
}
```

}

This is my PhoneRepistory:

```
public interface PhoneRepository extends CrudRepository<Phone, String> {
Phone findById(Long id);
@Transactional
Phone deleteById(Long id);

//sorting...
List<Phone> findByYearOfReleaseGreaterThan(Integer yearOfRelease, Sort sort);
//pagination...
List<Phone> findByQuarterOfRelease(String quarterOfRelease, Pageable pageable);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try to create spring data Specification for pagination and sorting

click [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) to read more how to create specification